# Automatically include bibliography file conditionally

Tags: bibtex, conditionals

I have nifty `common.sty` that I use is all my `.tex` papers (using `\input`) to provide uniform formatting, etc.

That `common.sty` uses `\addbibresource` to include a general bibliography that I use frequently in all my papers.

But, additionally, I'd like to automatically include specific bibliographies for some of my papers, even without having to explicitly do so in my `.tex` file. Specifically, I'd like the file `my-funky-paper.bib` to be automatically included, *if and only if* such a file lives in the same directory as `my-funky-paper.tex` file.

The catch is that I'd like to place the code that does this in the  `common.sty` file.

Can you teach me how? This would be easy to do in any programming language I know, but ss such a thing possible in Tex?

Comment: `\IfFileExists{\jobname.bib}{\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}}{}` perhaps?

Comment: Personally, i am against a file that suits all possible cases and rules them all. You can do it, but it will be a big lump of code that doesn't do anything useful. Consider 20 lines of code versus just on `\addbibressource` line in your tex.

Comment: @JoaoTavora: I've changed my suggestion in the meantime ;-) ... and what Johannes_B said is so true!

Comment: Johannes_B. It's a fair comment, but I'm a programmer,so I like to abstract away everything I can. And even in your specific example, it starts to pay off after 20 papers, which isn't much.

Comment: Johannes_B, if you can indeed do it, I ask you to please give me a hint as to how. Doesn't have to be a complete answer, I learn quickly :-)

Comment: @JoaoTavora: `\jobname` is exactly the thing to expand to the right basefile name, as I proposed in my first comment

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, it works perfectly, is only one line of harmless non-intrusive code in my sty file. Nowhere close to 20. So if you make this an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible way to do achieve such `\jobname.bib` - related behaviour, with `\IfFileExists`.

Please note that the whole TeX input path (i.e. available in  $TEXINPUTS environment variable, for example) is searched, so having two or more files with the same `\jobname` and the relevant `.bib` files as well this procedure might fail (i.e. it will use the first file it finds ;-))

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mysophisticatedcommonstuff}

\RequirePackage{biblatex}% use with options
% More packages to be loaded

\IfFileExists{\jobname.bib}{%
  \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}% Please note that there is an optional argument to \addbibresource!
}{ \typeout{No \jobname.bib file found}}

% more stuff

\endinput
```

Some importer document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mysophisticatedcommonstuff}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```